# Transform child out of bounds when trying to auto generate terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an "endless runner" game, and when I try to generate my terrain I get this error

*UnityException: Transform child out of bounds
GenreateTerrain.spawnTile () (at Assets/GenreateTerrain.cs:30)
GenreateTerrain.Start () (at Assets/GenreateTerrain.cs:17)*

I can't find out my problem, here is my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenreateTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject TerrainPrefab;
    public GameObject CurrentTerrain;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            spawnTile();
        }

    }

    public void  spawnTile()
    {
      CurrentTerrain = (GameObject)  Instantiate(TerrainPrefab, CurrentTerrain.transform.GetChild(0).position,Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: not the same issue

Comment: 1. it is, and the question doesn't contain enough information for us to explain exactly how it is. 2. from your comment in an answer, it looks like you need to save your changes to the prefab assigned to `TerrainPrefab` because its child appears to be unsaved to the prefab.

Comment: [new screenshot](https://imgshare.io/image/hierarchy.vimWu) now the prefab is saved

Comment: I'm pretty new to this so please tell me what info you would need

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the gameobject with the `GenreateTerrain` component attached to it shown in the inspector. We need to see which prefabs are assigned to `TerrainPrefab` and `CurrentTerrain`.

Comment: Need to continue tomorow thanks so far 

Answer (score 1):

Your CurrentTerrain GameObject doesn't have a child in the hierarchy.

.GetChild returns the indexed child in the object hierarchy.

Comment: It does have a child in the hierarchy..
see link for screenshot
[link](https://imgshare.io/image/hierarchy.viMF6)

Comment: Not the exact solution to your problem, but traversing the hierarchy like this is bad practice, for this exact reason. Use a public variable and drop your object in it, it will be much easier to debug.